# Is there an inbuilt PHP function to simply extract one regex match, in a single statement?

Tags: php, regex

I know that this works:

```
preg_match('/\d+/', '1234 Subject', $matches);
echo $matches[0]; // 1234
```

But I'm curious if there's a built-in function that just returns the first match, a la:

```
echo mysteryFunction('/\d+/', '1234 Subject'); // 1234
```

Without having to store the results in an array and having to then reference an array element separately?

If not, why not, is there a good reason?

Thanks

Comment: Naturally, very trivially - but I didn't want to reinvent the wheel and it must be a fairly common desire so I wondered if there was one already, and if not, why not?

Comment: because what you're asking for is not functionality - the functionality exists - what you want is just sugar.

Comment: `echo preg_replace('/^.*?(\d+).*$/', '$1', '1234 Subject');`

Comment: @Codemonkey https://3v4l.org/R17kD

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't. But for fun (I don't propose using this), if you use a capture group `()`:

```
echo preg_split('/(\d+)/', '1234 Subject', null, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE)[1];
```

Just like your `echo $matches[0];` you will get a *Notice: Undefined offset* if there is no match.

Comment: What if [there is no match](https://3v4l.org/HXCo2)? I don't think this is a good answer. I'd use it as a comment.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: It's not supposed to be a good answer, just fun.  Same as OP's `echo $matches[0];` if there is no match https://3v4l.org/sSK4V